# Add string to html and display in webview

Tags: java, android

I already have a `html` page named `myPage.html` in `assets` folder. It is like this..

```
<html>
<body>
Hello....
</body>
</html>
```

I need to load this `html` when no internet connection and also display a link to user in the `webview`. The link is dynamic and so
I cannot hard code it in `html`. Here is the code that I use for link -

```
getDataFromServer() + "html/MyRules.html"

                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(0);
                        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myPage.html"); //Also display link in webview but how???
                        }
```

So the requirement is to display the `html` and also the link in `webview`. The link should be clickable. How do I do this?

Comment: Open html file from assets, modify it as you need and open it after.

Comment: Could you please give me an example

Comment: First links in google will give you answers on each statement which I wrote in first message.